# "Dieing" vs "dying"

Tags: etymology, orthography

Which is the formally correct spelling, *dieing* or *dying*? Is there any history of the alternative spelling? I type *dieing* naturally, but my spellchecker marks it wrong. This is largely an etymology question in the development of the spelling of the word *dying*, since when I think of *dyeing* I see the word meaning *to stain a cloth with colors*.

Comment: I wonder why I see “ageing” and “eyeing” in good magazines, but never (e.g.) “takeing”.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If someone is passing away, then they are [*dying*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dying). Its origins are:

> late 13c., "death," verbal noun from die (v.). From mid-15c. as a pp. adj., "in the process of becoming dead."

Its confusable "*dieing*" [means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dieing):

> To cut, form, or stamp with or as if with a die.

Finally, *dyeing* means to stain something with color, with the [origins](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dyeing):

> c.1400, verbal noun and pp. adj. from dye.

Why is *dying* the gerund/verb form of *to die*? For one thing, it follows a [general rule](http://www.colegio-leones.com/Principal/webs/carlostirado/Bachillerato/InfinitiveAndGerund.pdf) of forming gerunds:

> The vowel group *-ie* is changed to -*y* before adding *-ing*.

As [this page](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-present-participle-of-verbs-ending-in-ie/) also says this, it is safe to say that this is a generally accepted rule. Other similar verbs are *tie* and *lie*. It is not a special case, but I cannot find an exact date for when this rule was created. It is worth noting that, whether or not this is correct, there are [early examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22dieing%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1837&lr=lang_en) of the spelling *dieing* for *dying* in the 1800s. This leads to the thought that the currently accepted form is because of a spelling reform at some point in time since then.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any specific reason that *die*, in the cutting sense, doesn't follow the rule and become *dying* as well, or is it just an unexplained exception?

Comment: @Samthere Not that I could find. I wonder if it is because "to die" isn't as accepted (and came after) so it took on a different rule.

Comment: Yeah, it seems many fewer sites mention *die* in that sense or *dieing* at all. Purely speculatively, perhaps it was introduced as an industry spelling to differentiate it.

Comment: "To cut, form, or stamp with or as if with a die." -- What does "die" refer to here? I'm assuming it's not the singular of "dice". I'm not sure how it could be "dye" (as in colour) either; I imagine that's pretty hard to cut with.

Comment: @mpen: die as a noun can either be the singular of dice, or it is a tool. Do a web search on "die tool" and look at the images. That will show you an answer better than I can with words.