# Spelling History: Dying vs Diing

Tags: orthography, conjugation, ing

As I recall, when I was in Grade School (40 years ago), the spelling of the word *dying* was taught as ***diing***.  Am I losing my mind or was that possible?

Comment: You are probably referring to 'dieing': http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/dieing-vs-dying

Comment: It is quite possible that your teacher taught you misinformation. It happens a lot. It is also quite possible that you are losing your mind. That happens a lot too. But misremembering something is no sure sign of its happening. As Cecily observes in *The Importance of Being Earnest,* memory "usually chronicles the things that have never happened, and couldn't possibly have happened."

Comment: @Brian: You'd best be careful about agreeing with OP's self-deprecation - I've [been called to account](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5074/2637) for doing the same thing myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Erm, not quite the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I was not agreeing, but merely withholding judgment in the absence of adequate evidence. "No, you're not losing your mind" may be comforting, but may also be an unwarranted or incorrect assumption.

Comment: @Brian: I was neither agreeing nor disagreeing in my (now censored) comment that occasioned that meta question. Apparently to some people, simply repeating someone else's words *as used of themselves* can be offensive. Presumably based on the principle that only negroes are allowed to use the n-word, I dunno.

Answer (score 2):

The OED does not mention *diing* and cites references such as this from 350 years ago:

> 1675   T. Brooks *Golden Key* 118   He that dyed on the Cross, was long a dying.

*Die* is an Early Middle English word (entered the language around 1100–1300), and was routinely spelled with a *y*:

> ... the word appears to have been in general use from the 12th cent., even in the s.w. dialects (see Napier in Hist. Holy Rood, E.E.T.S., 1894). The Middle English *dēȝen, dēghen* came regularly down to 1500 as *deye,* which was retained in the North as *dey, dē, dee* (still current from Lancashire to Scotland); but in standard English *dēghe* was in 14th cent. (in conformity with the common phonetic history of Old English *eh, eah, eoh,* as in *dye, eye, fly, high, lie, nigh, thigh, etc.*) narrowed to *diȝe, dighe,* whence the later *dye, die.*

Thus it's highly unlikely that the present participle was ever spelled without a *y.*

We cannot know whether you remember what your teacher said accurately or no; but if that is what you were taught, it appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Certainly. Probable? Unclear. Correct? No.